# Read contents of jsonArray using cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, ui-automation, cypress, web-frontend

I have a test.json file that has a jsonArray

```
[{
        "EMAIL": "email_1",
        "FIRST_NAME": "Daniel"
    },
    [{

        "EMAIL": "email_2",
        "FIRST_NAME": "John"
    }]
]
```

How can I leverage cypress `cy.readFile('path_to_json/test.json')` to read every element from this jsonArray ?
For ex:

How to read `email_2` , `John`

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working

```
cy.readFile('path_to_json/test.json').then(r => {
  r.forEach((item: any) => {
    cy.log(item.EMAIL);
  });
});
```

It does print

```
email_1
email_2`
```